# Outputting a Java map and mixing in HTML

Tags: java, html, dictionary

I am currently working on my own version of a glossary written in Java. Truthfully, this is of academic nature and I was hoping someone could point me in the first direction. Anyway, I am reading in text from a text file and putting the words and their corresponding definitions into a Map (Tree Map to be more specific). Everything works good from there. Everything is in the map as it should be.

Now I start to get to the part where I want to go into HTML and output the contents of the map. I know how to do that with iterators and that wasn't much of a problem. However, when I try to display the content mixed in with HTML I don't get all that I want. The page is ultimately supposed to look like this: http://cse.osu.edu/~weide/rsrg/sce/now/321/421/labs/lab10/glossary.html#book

And there is this particularly tricky part where if there's a term contained within a definition it should be clickable. Here is what I have so far. Again, if anyone could help me figure out why the main guts of the HTML aren't displaying I would appreciate it very much! By the way, the text file I'm getting things from is called: terms.txt, and the html file writing to is called glossary.html.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Glossary {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> dictionary = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    File htmlFile = new File(
            "/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/Lab10/src/glossary.html");
    File file = new File(
            "/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/Lab10/src/terms.txt");
    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(htmlFile));

    String term = null;
    String def = null;
    String key = null, value = null;
    String lead = null;
    String multiFinalDef = null;
     Set<String> checkValues = new HashSet<String>();
    String leftOver = null;
    boolean check = false;
    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(file);

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String keepTrack;
            boolean multi = false;
            String line = input.nextLine();

            term = line;
            def = input.nextLine();
            keepTrack = def;

            while (def.length() > 0 && input.hasNext()) {
                def = input.nextLine();

                if (def.length() > 0) {
                    multiFinalDef = " " + keepTrack + def;
                    multi = true;
                }

            }

            if (multi) {
                dictionary.put(term, multiFinalDef);

            } else {
                dictionary.put(term, keepTrack);

            }
            checkValues.add(term);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        out.write("<HTML>\n");
        out.write("<HEAD>\n");
        out.write("</HEAD>\n");
        out.write("<BODY>\n");
        out.write("<H1>Glossary</H1>\n");
        out.write("<HR /\n");
        out.write("<H2>Index</H2>\n");
        out.write("<UL>\n");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Set s = dictionary.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = s.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {


        Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();

        // getKey is used to get key of map.
        key = (String) m.getKey();

        // getValue is used to get the value of the key in map.
        value = (String) m.getValue();

        // this is just so I know the output from the map is actually correct. And indeed it is.
        System.out.println("Key:\t\t\tValue\n " + key + "\t\t\t " + value
                + "\n");
        try {
            out.write("<LI><A HREF=\"#" + key + "\">" + key + "</A></LI>\n");
            out.write("</UL>\n");
            out.write("<HR />\n");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    out.write("<H2>Terms and Definitions</H2>\n");
    out.write("<UL>\n" + "<P>\n");

    iterator = s.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry temp = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();

        // getKey is used to get key of map.
        String keyTwo = (String) temp.getKey();

        // getValue is used to get the value of the key in map.
        String valueTwo = (String) temp.getValue();

        out.write("<H3><A NAME=\" " + keyTwo + "/><B><I><FONT COLOR=\"red\">"
                + keyTwo + "</FONT></I></B></LI></H3>\n");

    for(String getTerm : checkValues){

        if (valueTwo.contains(getTerm)) {

            check = true;
            int foundTermPosition = valueTwo.indexOf(getTerm);
            lead = valueTwo.substring(0, foundTermPosition - 1);
            //fix left over..
            leftOver = valueTwo.substring(foundTermPosition, valueTwo.length());
            out.write(lead);
            out.write("<A HREF=\"#" + keyTwo + "\">" + keyTwo + "</A>");
            out.write(leftOver + "\n");
            //out.write("</blockquote>\n");

        }
    }
            if( check == false)
            {
            out.write(lead + " " + valueTwo);
            }
        }



        //System.out.println(valueTwo + leftOver);

        // used to put words defined in file mentioned in definition
        // with hyperlinks to their associated locations, and output the
        // definition.

    out.write("</P>\n" + "</UL>\n");
    out.write("</BODY>\n");
    out.write("</HTML>");

    out.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the time your program reaches

```
out.write("<H2>Terms and Definitions</H2>\n");
out.write("<UL>\n" + "<P>\n");

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   ...
```

the iterator doesn't have any more items left, as it gets exhausted on the first while loop a few lines before, while you're printing the index. To iterate through the map again, you'll need to call the iterator method again. So the block above would become:

```
out.write("<H2>Terms and Definitions</H2>\n");
out.write("<UL>\n" + "<P>\n");

iterator = s.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that for a brief second yesterday and then wrongly dismissed it. I will make the changes you suggested and then report back. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: Yeah, that worked better. So now the guts are showing but now I just need to make the hyper links show for things in the definitions that are actually terms. Because of my inexperience with maps in Java, I put all of the terms in a set and am using a foreach loop to go through each definition and see if anything in there matches what is in the set. It ALMOST worked, except when I used "contains" it said something like "words" was a match for "word" when that is not true and not what I want. Thinking about using a tokenizer...Is a certain method better than contains for this?

Comment: Yes, you can use a `StringTokenizer` to extract the words in a text, like so (note that I tried to leave the variable names unchanged even though I would recommend you spend some time changing them to more meaningful names):

    String textToTokenize = valueTwo;
    String delimiters = " ,;.";
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(textToTokenize, delimiters);

    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String currentToken = tokens.nextToken();
        if (getTerm.equals(currentToken)) {
           ...
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to generate html documents. In my humble opinion, the best and generic approach in your case - **use any of template engines**. For example - [Apache Velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Velocity).

It takes a few minutes to look through this [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1228-velocity.html?page=1)